# What is this unusual jumper/busbar?

Tags: identification

Metal. Length is 5/8", pitch is 0.1". Ruler is centimetres.

This thing is really useful because you can plug it into breadboard and attach a probe clip to the square tab and the connection is extremely secure. It can also be used to bridge two rows directly next to each other.

Unfortunately I only have one and I would like to buy some more.

I think I originally found it in some old computer hardware where it was used as a configuration jumper. Instead of the usual way of having pins on the board, this one had a socket and you plugged this thing into it.

[image: jumper thing]

Comment: Quick search on digikey found this rough equivalent: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/999-11-210-10-000000/475742

Comment: Buy 2 pin headers and some solder and make as many as you need.